# Firebase ML Kit

Tags: firebase, flutter, kotlin, firebase-machine-learning

Trying to use Firebase ml kit for label but getting error below with version;  firebase_ml_vision: ^0.9.10

**Error**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
 lib\main.dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[19.0.
  2]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

  Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-co
  mmon@[19.0.2], but play-services-vision-common version was 19.1.0.

  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
  ifact with the issue.
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@{strictly 24.1.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_ml_vision' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@20.0.
  0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@{strictly 19.1.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-bom@26.2.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label@{strictly 18.0.4}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-bom@{strictly 26.2.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@{strictly 20.0.0}

  For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
  endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
  github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }" to your bu
  ild.gradle file.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

After searching on github, somehow with edit below, app is running now, but when i try to use mlkit, getting error below

**Edit 2**

```
   dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label:18.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.2'
}
```

**Error in App**

```
D/MediaScannerConnection( 8393): Scanned /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.temp_name/files/Pictures/e235923b-70f9-404a-aa0b-930333cceea96952909717190624838.jpg to null
I/flutter ( 8393): /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.temp_name/files/Pictures/scaled_e235923b-70f9-404a-aa0b-930333cceea96952909717190624838.jpg
W/DynamiteModule( 8393): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ica not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 8393): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ica:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.ica:0
W/DynamiteModule( 8393): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.ica not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 8393): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.ica:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.ica:0
E/Vision  ( 8393): Error loading optional module com.google.android.gms.vision.ica: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/LabelerNativeHandle( 8393): Native handle not yet available. Reverting to no-op handle.
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: I was about to send error as code, but get error 'too many code in your question'.

Comment: I don't understand where the dependency on `firebase-ml-vision@20.0. 0` comes from as `firebase-bom:26.2.0` should only include `firebase-ml-vision@24.1.0`.

Comment: Can you please check new edit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're including `firebase-bom:26.2.0`, that determines the versions of all Firebase SDKs you use. So remove the version numbers from all other Firebase SDK dependencies in your build.gradle to get rid of the version conflict.

Comment: Thanks for answer but still getting same error.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the new `build.gradle` and the exact new error message (preferable as text btw, as posting screenshots of textual contents is a lossy operation).

Comment: Edited with using, text but can't format it like code because of error ' too many code', hope it's still more useful than image.